# Row selection from Grid not working

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a grid, and have 2 columns `Name, Age`. There are several rows in this grid (like 20-30 records). Now when i click on a row, i need to get the name of the Person and display it on a Label.

I thought, if i use `getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store)` i could get the details of the selected row value. But, this is not working. Can someone help me ?

```
 xtype: 'gridpanel',
                            height: 500,
                            width: 800,
                            title: 'Person Grid',
                            store: 'Person',

                            viewConfig: {
                                getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store) {
                                    console.log("Print the selected row data and set to label");
                                    console.log(record);
                                    console.log(rowIndex);
                                    console.log(rowParams);
                                }
                            },
                            columns: [ .....
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing here is actually changing how you render these cells. So basically `getRowClass` will get called one time for each row when your grid is rendered.

You need to listen to grid `selectionchange` and get selected row there.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you can use this:

```
yourGrid.getSelectionModel().on('selectionchange', function(grid, model, object) {
    var model = model[0].data;
    yourPanel.getForm().findField('fieldName').setValue(model.name);

});
```

`yourPanel` is panel that field are included and assuming the field are in a form.